# null value in column violates not-null constraint PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'm trying to import a csv into PostgreSQL database table.When i executing the following query:

[image]

My table name is trendmania_video

```
COPY public.trendmania_video FROM 'C:\Users\Shahnawaz Irfan\Desktop\0.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

a following error occurred:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "v_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, UgzYr_WZlR73yFBnRdx4AaABAg, yar 
kindly ap urdu m b toturial bna lety wordpress k liye to hma..., null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).
CONTEXT:  COPY trendmania_video, line 10: ",,UgzYr_WZlR73yFBnRdx4AaABAg,yar 
kindly ap urdu m b toturial bna lety wordpress k liye to hmari b he..."
SQL state: 23502
```

I also tried manually by using import button, but same error occurs.

Comment: Have values for each row in `v_id`, or make the column nullable

Comment: @JGH v_id coloumn has primary key constraint  and when i add v_id coloumn nullable, an error occurs "set primary_key feild as null=False"

Comment: a PK cannot be null. How should this value be created?

Comment: yes same issue stuck me a lot? Tell me the solution.

Comment: It depends on your use case. You can use a sequence, or you can populate the column in the csv.... or you can use another column for the PK, or...

Comment: No, i want to import same csv data with same records into db

Comment: So you want the user community to assign the database PK for new entries. That is a very, very bad plan. And the fallacy populating your database directly form spreadsheets.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your table `trendmania_video`, you have `v_id` to be not null which causes this issue. You one option is to get ride of the not null constrain:

```
ALTER TABLE public.trendmania_video ALTER COLUMN v_id DROP NOT NULL;
```

If this is a new table then it's better to recreate it with a new table with an auto-cremented `id` while `v_id` is another value.

```
CREATE TABLE trendmania_video(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   v_id VARCHAR
   --the rest of the columns
);
```

Comment: ERROR:  column "v_id" is in a primary key
    SQL state: 42P16

Comment: i can't fill records in v_id because its our project criteria.

Comment: Or creating a temporary table as a working space to get things loaded and cleaned before copying to the final table. I find this two-step process to be easier than trying to fix the CSV or breaking existing table constraints.

Comment: @ShahnawazIrfan I've updated my answer with an alternative. You can re-create the table be adding a separated auto-cemented id and v_id as a normal column.

Comment: Dear, i can't set multiple primary keys field but another error occurs after executing "multiple primary keys for table trendmania_video" are not allowed.

Comment: In the new table, The `id` column should be the only primary key.

Comment: yes, i deleted old one and create a new one and also set another field as a primary key and use v_id without primary key when i execute multiple primary keys error shows me again and again

Comment: Can you share the full SQL statement you use to create a new table?

Comment: i'm creating table using python Django models

Comment: Can you share how you do that in the question please?

Answer (score 0):

if you have this autogenerated id in your entity , just delete it :
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)